# Android Passing Variable doesn't seem to click

Tags: android

I have created a random number and would like to pass it along to use in the same file just different class. Please help:

```
public void Start() {
int number = random.nextInt(3); // Gives a number such that 0 <= number < 2
```

then a few lines down I try to use `number` but it's telling me it's not a variable to use:

```
    public void renderBackground(Canvas canvas) {

    //TODO: you may wish to change background colors from here
    if(number=="0") {
```

any kind of help is great appreciated!

Comment: could I see more code? I think I see the problem but im not sure without more code

Comment: Is the second class an inner class of the first?

Comment: that's pretty much it... i closed the top with } and started another activity trying to use the same random number picked up top...

Comment: @DanielNugent no it is not..

Comment: The comparison should be number==0, I.e. remove the quotes

Comment: `number cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: how can you use local variable of one method to another method ..your variable scope is limited to start();

Comment: Are both classes Activities?

Comment: If the method is in the same class just declare it at the top
private int number;
its hard to help with that little code

Comment: you can create third class for common variables make them public static and access wherever you want .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the scope of variable `number`. I'm not sure you are using inner class or a separate class.

If it's a `inner class`, then declare the `number` at top of the first class like,

```
class Firstclass
{
  public int number; // scope is public it can be accessed anywhere in class

   method();
   ...
   ...
class Secondclass
{

  method()
  {
     System.out.println("Your number is : " + number); // here you are accessing variable `number`
  }
 }
}
```

Also, try to change

```
if(number=="0") { 

to

if(number==0) {
```

Comment: tried doing `public int number = random.nextInt(3); // Gives a number such that 0 <= number < 2` and got this: `Illegal modifier for parameter number; only final is permitted`

Comment: where are you adding public int number? if it's inside a method, you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are initializing 'number' inside a class, not the main class.
initialize number inside the main class then modify it in your method. ex: